# How to construct a new value in a public function using initializers from an internal protocol?

Tags: swift, generics, initialization, swift-protocols

Say I want to expose some functionality as public API, but part of the implementation refers to internal protocols:

```
public protocol P {
    var foo: Int { get }
}

internal protocol Q {
    init(from: [String])
}

public struct S: P, Q {
    public var foo: Int = 0
    public init() {}    

    internal init(from: [String]) {
        precondition(from.count > 0)
        self.foo = Int(from[0])!
    }
}
```

This would be some data object that only my own module can construct (from some data representation) but that users of the module can use for their own purposes.

Say I want to provide some service that takes such a value and returns a new one of the same type:

```
public class ProviderOfThings {
    public func map<T: P>(before: T) -> T {
        return T(from: [String(before.foo + 1)])
    }
}
```

This does not compile; there is no suitable initializer on `T`.

How can I call the constructor I (internally) know to be there in a generic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can cast the value to the internal protocol type and access the initializer from there:

```
public static func map<T: P>(before: T) -> T {
    return type(of: before as! Q).init(
        from: [String(before.foo + 1)]
    ) as! T
}
```

We can even do without a value of the type (thanks, [Hamish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2976878/hamish)!):

```
public static func make<T: P>() -> T {
    return (T.self as! Q.Type).init(
        from: ["0"]
    ) as! T
}
```

If there are (or can be) implementations of `P` that do not also conform to `Q`, the cast to `Q` needs to be guarded, obviously:

```
guard let beforeQ = before as? Q else { ... }
// or
guard before is Q else { ... }

// respectively
guard T.self is Q.Type else { ... }
```

The other cast `as! T` is safe: we call an initializer of `T`, after all. Therefore, if guarded, this solution can not cause runtime errors.

Find the full code with examples [here](https://gist.github.com/reitzig/e2f2c568b0723a68a347509083d60d89).

Comment: I found this by accident; syntax completion showed `.init(...)` to be available on the result of `type(of:)`. Can we get such values by other means? What *is* the return type of this function, anyway?

Comment: `type(of:)` isn't *technically* a function – it's the [dynamic type expression](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Expressions.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/postfix-self-expression). The static type of what it evaluates to depends on the static type of what you use it on. For example, using it on a `String` instance yields a `String.Type`, using it on an `Any` instance yields an `Any.Type`.

Comment: The static version of the cast would be `(T.self as! Q.Type).init(from: ...` btw. It will create a new instance of whatever the static type of `T` is, rather than the dynamic type.

Comment: @Hamish Cool, thanks! I'll have to think about whether I want the dynamic of static type. I think the dynamic one, though... the static type would be `P` which won't cast over to Q.

Comment: @Hamish I expanded my answer to incorporate your comment; we need this cast for methods that don't get a value of type `T`! However, I find that it seems to resolve to the dynamic type, anyway; or, if it's static, the compiler does its magic. Either way, the correct constructors are called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be to declare `map` as follows:

```
public func map<T: P & Q>(before: T) -> T
```

and make `Q` public, possibly prefixing it with `_` if it shouldn't be used by external code.

Comment: No. I _don't_ want to `Q` to be public, that's the point. Otherwise I could just do `P: Q` and be done with it. And I absolutely won't replace accessibility definitions with identifier conventions; this is not PHP!

Comment: The `_` prefix is common practice in Swift (for example in the standard library). This is a tradeoff between force-casting (bypassing the type system) and the `_` prefix (bypassing the access system).

Comment: Aside from a huge number of `__`-prefixed top-level functions (which look like "don't use me in Swift, anyway), I am not aware of any such names in the standard library. Are those what you mean? If not, can you give an example, please?

Comment: No I mean single-underscore prefixes on public protocols, functions, and types. For example while browsing the files in [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/stdlib/public/core) directory it is hard to not notice them.

Comment: Can you point to a specific *public* member with such a name, please? Because I checked some files and found none. It's true that there are *internal* members with `_`-names but those don't support your point.

Comment: E.g. `public protocol _RandomAccessIndexable` in RandomAccessCollection.swift.

Comment: Thanks. I note, though, that this usage does not seem to encourage this pattern. Quite the opposite, in fact: "FIXME(ABI)#54 (Recursive Protocol Constraints): there is no reason for this protocol to exist apart from missing compiler features that we emulate with it. rdar://problem/20531108 This protocol is almost an implementation detail of the standard library." So it's hack/workaround, at least here.

Comment: Yes, as it is in my proposed solution. You have a public function whose generic parameter needs to conform to `Q`, thus `Q` should be public (otherwise users of that function may not be able to pass an appropriate argument to it). I don't see a reason why it couldn't be public, but if this is true for some reason, you can use force-casting or the _ prefix as a workaround until a better design. The _ prefix won't cause crashes at least, while force-casting might.

Comment: I expanded my answer; as far as I can tell, it can not cause crashes either, if the casts are guarded properly. In summary, I don't see any advantage of your solution. (You are free to disagree, obviously.)